# Codename one build error with new Netbeans installation

Tags: codenameone

I recently starting using a new Mac for development, and I have a cn1 app I've been working on on a Windows machine for a while.  I installed Netbeans and the cn1 plugin, but I can't run the project or send a build.  The error I get is this:

```
ant -f /Users/yaakov/Development/workspace/medonline_cn1 build-for-android-device
No GUI Entries available
init:
deps-clean:
Updating property file: /Users/yaakov/Development/workspace/medonline_cn1/build/built-clean.properties
Deleting directory /Users/yaakov/Development/workspace/medonline_cn1/build
refresh-libs:
Deleting directory /Users/yaakov/Development/workspace/medonline_cn1/lib/impl
clean:
copy-android-override:
Created dir: /Users/yaakov/Development/workspace/medonline_cn1/build/classes
Copying 8 files to /Users/yaakov/Development/workspace/medonline_cn1/build/classes
copy-libs:
Copying 96 files to /Users/yaakov/Development/workspace/medonline_cn1/build/classes
deps-jar:
Updating property file: /Users/yaakov/Development/workspace/medonline_cn1/build/built-jar.properties
compile-css:
/Users/yaakov/Development/workspace/medonline_cn1/build.xml:37: Could not find designer_1.jar file at path /Users/yaakov/.codenameone/designer_1.jar
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

The directory /Users/yaakov/.codenameone doesn't even exist.  There is /Users/yaakov/.cn1 directory, however, but it's empty.  The project is a GUI builder project.  I'm running Java 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you installed the [Codename One plugin](https://www.codenameone.com/) on NetBeans just double click the res file. This will launch the designer and create that directory. Everything should work as expected after that.